# Can someone say what is wrong to read csv FIle on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am transforming json data into csv files with a script called parser.py and counting them in another script called analyzer.py. My problem is that the output CSV files are correct but when I try to read the files in analyzer.py the lines have broken in many others in the dataframe and the new lines are not following the order of the columns and putting no value. Sorry for bad English I'm so sad about this :(

CSV columns:

```
 status_id, created_at, user_id, user_screen_name, status_text, hashtags,
 user_metions, url, status_fav_count, status_rewtweet_count, is_retweet, 
 ori_status_id, ori_creted_at, ori_user_id, ori_user_screen_name, 
 ori_text, ori_hashtags, ori_user_metions, ori_urls, ori_fav_count,
 ori_rewtweet_count, is_quoted, quoted_status_id, quoted_status_creted_at,
 quoted_status_user_id, quoted_status_screen_name, quoted_text,
 quoted_hashtags, quoted_user_metions, quoted_urls, quoted_fav_count, 
 quoted_rewtweet_count
```

Example:

> 1106517910707679235,2019-03-15 11:30:02,19888170,Cout_ma,RT @Marish_:
>   kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk , ,0,0,True,110651       6443468845061,Fri Mar
>   15 11:24:12 +0000 2019,61990620,Marish_,kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
>   ,,,,5,6,True,1106513884314324992,Fri Mar 15 11:14:02 +0000
>   2019,14594813,folha,Ruralistas reclamam de vi�~C©s anti-China no
>   governo Bolsonaro ,,,160,34

output when a perform a read test:

> Pandas(Index=39498, status_id='URL HERE', created_at=nan, user_id=nan,
>   user_screen_name='URL HERE ', status_text='0', hashtags='0',
>   user_metions='False', url=nan, status_fav_count=nan,
>   status_rewtweet_count=nan, is_retweet=nan, ori_status_id=nan,
>   ori_creted_at=nan, ori_user_id=nan, ori_user_screen_name=nan,
>   ori_text=nan, ori_hashtags=nan, ori_user_metions='False',
>   ori_urls=nan, ori_fav_count=nan, ori_rewtweet_count=nan,
>   is_quoted=nan, quoted_status_id=nan, quoted_status_creted_at=nan,
>   quoted_status_user_id=nan, quoted_status_screen_name=nan,
>   quoted_text=nan, quoted_hashtags=nan, quoted_user_metions=nan,
>   quoted_urls=nan, quoted_fav_count=nan, quoted_rewtweet_count=nan)

write csv code:

> ```
>     df = pandas.DataFrame(to_csv,columns=['status_id',
>                                'created_at',
>                                'user_id',
>                                'user_screen_name',
>                                    .
>                                    .
>                                    .
>                                     ])
>     df = df.sort_values(by='status_id')
>     df.to_csv(to + index + '_' + start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + '.csv',index=False,encoding='utf8')
> ```

read csv code:

```
 data = pd.read_csv(path + '/' + name) # var name contains the csv file name
for i in data.itertuples():
   print(i)
```

Comment: Make sure the tweet text or other fields do not contain the CSV separator you use (comma in this case) otherwise when reading the lines won't be able to tell if the separator is meant to separate or was just a char in the original text.

Comment: @kekec if a have comma in a quoted string like "this is a string with comma ,"will the problem persist?

Comment: If strings are quoted, the problem should not persist.

Comment: I suggest you try editing down your JSON file to a few examples that recreate your problem and then [edit] your question to include that. Also add enough code for us to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tweet text or other fields do not contain the CSV separator you use (comma in this case) otherwise when reading the lines won't be able to tell if the separator is meant to separate or was just a char in the original text. 
If strings are quoted, the problem should not persist.